# WSL- gdb - Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

Tags: python, linux, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My system is Ubuntu18.04 under WSL, the Python version is 3.10, and the default python3 in the system has been uninstalled.

Python3.10 is linked to `/usr/bin/python3` by using a symbolic link.

The problem is when I try to use gdb to debug a program.

With no PATH added, the error is

```sh
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

According to similar problems, I tried to export the installation directory and bin directory of python3.10 in turn, and added $PATH and $PYTHONPATH respectively, but none of them could solve the problem.

I suspect it may be something wrong with my current version of python3's environment variables. There was a problem that some modules in dist-packages could not be found before. After I migrated to python3/lib/python3.10, it was solved. I don't know if it is related to the current problem.

I tried to debug other programs with gdb, and found that it can't process any gdb command now, and the above error will be reported.

Comment: "I tried to export the installation directory and bin directory of python3.10 in turn" Show what you have done by pasting the exact commands.

Comment: `export PYTHONHOME=$PYTHONHOME:/usr/bin` `export PYTHONHOME=$PYTHONHOME:/usr/lib/python3` `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`

Comment: This doesn't look correct. You said /usr/bin/python3 is a symbolic link. Where does it link to? How did you install python3?

Comment: It link to `/usr/lib/python3/bin/python3`. I compiled python 3.10 from source code, The generated files are under `/usr/lib/python3`. My python works fine except now I use C to call python.

Comment: I just found out that my gdb is completely unusable

Comment: I don't know why  your commands to not work for you, but your method of managing Python is not a good idea for a number of reasons. Reinstall system Python, install whatever Python version you need *under yout $HOME* or *under /usr/local*,  and use `virtualenv` to manage it.